# MultiStore Magento error

Tags: magento2, multistore

I have a secondary website under the root folder.
I have example.com as the main domain. Create a new website with website code ir. And the url links to ir folder. Added `.htaccess` and `index.php` with the modification as per the website load. Created symbolic links ln -s `/var/www/html/example/app/ app etc`. Still after doing all this when i load the secondary site example.com/ir the css url are `example.com/ir/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_GB/css/styles-m.css` which does not exist.

Comment: You need to create symbolic link for pub folder for your new website.

Comment: can you copy/paste index.php from /ir/ subfolder? Probably missing correct path for media/ js/css.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Run this Below Command.

```
php bin/magento ma:en && php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento s:d:c && php bin/magento s:s:d en_US && php bin/magento s:s:d en_GB && php bin/magento ma:di
```